# Customize EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add a microphone image button on the right of the EditText inside EditTextPreference so when this image button is hit, the Recognizer will be triggered to convert speech to text.

Comment: just add (android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/microphone") and some Left padding or margin to your Edittext -- so its (Edittext --- Microphone Icon) If you havent got any more icons after the microphone then add (android:layout_alignParentRight="true") and some margin or padding right to the Microphone icon -- that should align them Ok as im using this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

> **Speech To Text**

For Speech to text you take some other example... or Enabling Offline Mode.

setOnTouchListener Method used for your click you want take right drawable

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;


public class demon extends Activity {


        EditText editComment;
    private final int SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE = 1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.demo);
             editComment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);


            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                    new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
            if (activities.size() == 0)
            {
                editComment.setEnabled(false);
                editComment.setText("Recognizer not present");
            }
            editComment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                    final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                    final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                    final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if(event.getRawX() >= (editComment.getRight() - editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                            // your action here

                            startSpeechToText();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


        }


    private void startSpeechToText() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Speak something...");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Speech recognition is not supported in this device.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    String text = result.get(0);
                    editComment.setText(text);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

> **Text To speech**

**demo.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;



public class demo extends Activity {


    EditText editComment;
    TextToSpeech t1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);
         editComment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editComment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= (editComment.getRight() - editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        // your action here

                        String toSpeak = editComment.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void onPause(){
        if(t1 !=null){
            t1.stop();
            t1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**demo.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/edittext"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Enabling Offline Mode

[image]
<sub>(source: [androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/1.png))</sub>

Comment: your solution looks good but as you type does the microphone icon disappear and the (x) icon appears so you can clear the Text??

Comment: Yes Sure You can change it when you take value in edittext than change the right drawable  editComment.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);

When value not empty of edittext than on touch lister clear the value and change drawale to microphone icon and take code as show...

Comment: Sorry for bad english  @Tasos

Comment: its ok i understand. So as you type change to (x) icon by code using Textwatcher and have one click listener to get the icon name and say (if mic icon do this else clear text). Ill give your code a try looks better than my comment solution. Thanks -- upvoting :)